# Convert.ToString returns `System.Byte[]` and not the actual data as GROUP_CONCAT returns BLOB

Tags: c#, mysql

I have one method which is calling **MySQL** procedure. Below is part of the procedure:

```
SELECT AR.alert_id AS AlertId,
        AR.rule_id AS RuleId,
        AR.name AS RuleName,
        AR.rule_type AS RuleType, 
        AR.description AS Description, 
        (SELECT group_concat(occured_event_id separator ', ') 
            FROM alert_rule_event
            WHERE alert_rule_id = AR.id) AS OccuredEventIds,
FROM alert_rule AR
```

C# code:

```
alertRuleEntity.AlertId = Convert.ToInt32(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["AlertId"]);
alertRuleEntity.RuleId = Convert.ToInt32(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleId"]);
alertRuleEntity.RuleName = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleName"]);
alertRuleEntity.RuleType = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["RuleType"]);
alertRuleEntity.Description = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["Description"]);
alertRuleEntity.OccuredEventIds = Convert.ToString(dtAlertRuleEntityList.Rows[index]["OccuredEventIds"]);
```

It is returning values as follows:

[image]

It is able to read all column values properly. But In case of column `OccuredEventIds` it is giving value as `System.Byte[]` rather than its actual value. What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? It looks to be some kind of binary type.

Comment: occured_event_id is INT type. But procedure is returning comma separated ids.

Comment: Share some C# code that you write to read the data from PROC...

Comment: Ah, right - what datatype do you want to get back? I don't think you can return an array from a sproc call, like this. You may have to cast your group_concat as a varchar - and parse to integers when you read it out

Comment: I want to read it as string.

Comment: @Pandian: I have added my C# code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making following change to my procedure it worked:

```
(SELECT group_concat(CONVERT(occured_event_id, CHAR(8)) separator ', ') 
FROM alert_rule_event
WHERE alert_rule_id = AR.id) AS OccuredEventIds
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try casting your parameters to `group_concat` to a `varchar` first as the [documentation says that it converts binary parameters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to a `BLOB`.

```
SELECT AR.alert_id AS AlertId,
        AR.rule_id AS RuleId,
        AR.name AS RuleName,
        AR.rule_type AS RuleType, 
        AR.description AS Description, 
        (SELECT group_concat(cast(occured_event_id as char(20)) separator ', ') 
            FROM alert_rule_event
            WHERE alert_rule_id = AR.id) AS OccuredEventIds,
FROM alert_rule AR
```

Comment: After making this change to procedure it is giving me SQL syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Group_Concat Return BLOB type so only you get Bytes as output,

**Sol-1 :**

Change the value of the `group_concat_max_len` system variable to `512`
and Restart the MySql Service

*See here :*  [Why GROUP_CONCAT returns BLOB?](http://www.logikdev.com/2010/02/11/why-group_concat-returns-blob/)

OR

**Sol-2 :**

SET `"respect binary flags=false;"` in your Connection string

Hope this helps you....